# Accessing Spire.PdfViewer.Wpf.dll via Nuget

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, nuget, spire

I am working with Spire.PdfViewer for a WPF Application.
After downloading the package, the `Spire.PdfViewer.Wpf.dll` should be found in the bin folder of my project. Unfortunately I'm not able to find the library on my network.

The documentation is found under this link:

http://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDFViewer/Demos/Quick-guide/WPF-How-to-add-Controls-to-Toolbox.html

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the description for Spire.PDFViewer NuGet package on the official site, it mentioned that “With Spire.PDFViewer, developers can **create any WinForms application** to open, view and print PDF document in C# and Visual Basic on .NET”. It is a free version for .NET.

For the version for WPF, you need to buy download the Spire.PDFViewer Pack from below link, which contains Spire.PDFViewer for WPF components.

http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-viewer-wpf-introduce.html#.V8Uzrih94z4

After installing, please choose the Spire.PdfViewer.Wpf.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\e-iceblue\Spire.PdfViewer\Bin\WPF4.0. Then you can add PDFViewer controls into Toolbox.